# Instagram API with CURL slow, jquery ajax fast

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram, file-get-contents

I have problem with Instagram api using PHP.
Instagram API url is following:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=c32bb75ba2b449dc93b5461a84d9003e

Using this: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

with following code in my php script:

```
<?php 
$instagram = new Instagram('c32bb75ba2b449dc93b5461a84d9003e');
$response = $instagram->getPopularMedia();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

script execute sometimes longer then 40sec, sometimes no results.

Same problem is with simple call:

```
<?php  
echo file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=c32bb75ba2b449dc93b5461a84d9003e')
```

With simple jquery AJAX request like this(on same server):

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=c32bb75ba2b449dc93b5461a84d9003e",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

result come always very fast.

I try this two ways on different servers and results are same. Also in PHP class I try use file_get_content instead CURL but everything is same.

Please help (with PHP).

Answer (score 1):

- When using AJAX, *you* (speaking of your web browser) opens the connection to instagram.
- When using PHP, your web server opens the connection to instagram.

This means: the connection from your web server to instagram is probably slow because either your web server is far away or uses a very bad route to it or (the more probable explanation) you (your code) are sitting on a very poor hoster which limits bandwith from scripts within web servers.

You can debug that by trying to get contents of other web services or web sites.

Comment: @Vlatko - no is not. modpagespeed is for optimizing speed of the webpage by minifiying it, compressing it etc. It will have no effect on the issue with instagram

Comment: Just to add a comment here, Instagram's API is very very slow and sadly has nothing to do with server locations, but more to do with something at their end. Even with the simplest request, we're finding it takes up to 20seconds to get a response at times.

Answer (score 0):

add Connection: close to the HTTP header you send.
in PHP:
header('Connection: close');